# Why does ASP.NET MVC 4 with IList for editor not write index notation properly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a peculiar situation in which referencing 'model in my editor template produces a malformed index 'name' field:

**Editor**

```
@model IList<BillingRateItem>

@for (int i = 0;i < this.Model.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => this.Model[i].BillingRateItemID)
}
```

The hidden field produced includes a period before the index, which is problematic:

**HTML Rendered**

```
<input id="Model_BillingRateItems__0__BillingRateItemID" name="Model.BillingRateItems.[0].BillingRateItemID" type="hidden" value="9">
```

**What I want Rendered**

Note that 'Model.BillingRateItems[0]' has no period between the name and the index.  This is good!

```
<input id="Model_BillingRateItems__0__BillingRateItemID" name="Model.BillingRateItems[0].BillingRateItemID" type="hidden" value="9">
```

**EDIT - This is an example of the view calling the editor**

```
@model BillingRateViewModel // has multiple BillingRateItems

@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.BillingRateItems,"BillingRateItemsGrid")
```

Note:
When I change the Editor to accept the parent object (e.g. BillingRate) the indexing works fine.  Maybe the conclusion is simply the all editors will begin with a '.' regardless of the context.  In the case of Enumerables it will add the '.[].' even though this does the native model binder no help in reconstructing the object.

Comment: I tried the exactly same thing you did, and my result HTML was name="[].BillingRateItemID", that will me binded correctly for the Default Model Binder! Which version of ASP.NET are you using? Do you have the Web Update v4?

Comment: I've googled Web Update v4 and I'm not exactly sure what you mean.  I have MVC 4 (version 4.0.20713.0) installed.

Comment: Your version is outdated!

Comment: Ok...good to know.  Thanks for the heads-up.  I'll update it in the morning.

Comment: Use foreach instead of for loop

Comment: @RameshRajendran The actual code is in a WebGrid, but the result is the same whether it's a foreach or for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly wich is the issue with the version of the MVC assembly that you are using, but looks like some bug that I can't reproduce on the latest version that you can install from the Visual Studio Extensions and Updates menu.

You can create this hidden field using the `@Html.Hidden` this way:

```
@Html.Hidden("[" + i + "].BillingRateItemID", this.Model[i].BillingRateItemID);
```

The produced HTML will look like, where `i` will be the index of each item and the value will assume the `BillingRateItemID`:

```
<input name="[1].BillingRateItemID" type="hidden" value="1">
```

Then the default Model Binder will take care about the list correctly.

Comment: MVC5 fixes this!  So to recap, when using MVC4 with an enumerable property in an editor the name generated erroneously puts the brackets after a 'dot', to the name looks like <enumerableproperty>.[<index>].<property>.  

MVC5 corrects this to look like <enumerableproperty>[<index>].<property>.  Thanks for all the help and workarounds.  Manually constructing the name was an option (albeit an ugly one).

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
@model IList<BillingRateItem>

@for (int i = 0;i < this.Model.Count(); i++)
{  

    <input name="Model.BillingRateItems["+@i+"].BillingRateItemID[] type="hidden" value="1"> 
}
```